# Is there a list, directory, or review of PPAs that is worth a look? Or can you share links to some notable PPAs that you know of or use?

Tags: ppa

IMHO a list of well-maintained PPAs is a useful commodity for a Ubuntu user to have. Perhaps some of you have links of this kind to share? Or maybe you've seen a review or list of PPAs (a blog post maybe) by someone, or some kind of PPA directory, etc.?

I am especially interested in fresh and useful packages targeting 10.04, 10.10 and 11.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out Ubuntu Tweak? Not exactly what you are asking for, but I find the PPAs you can install via Ubuntu Tweak to be of high quality.

http://ubuntu-tweak.com/source/category/

Answer (score 2):

There is a search program - engine for finding PPA's. I thing is very useful.
[Y PPA MANAGER](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/y-ppa-manager-easily-search-add-remove.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a special PPA-list, but my best source of great PPAs is [Webup8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/)

These Guys are also the maintainers of Y PPA Manager.

Answer (score 1):

there isn't a list but you can search in Personal Package Archives (PPA).

**[Personal Package Archives for Ubuntu](https://edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas)**

just enter the program to search and it will show all associated ppa with this program. (exam. banshee)